# Dynamic Text with surrounding line, whose container has a background image

Tags: css

I need to implement something like this..

```
-------------------------
|                        |
|                        |
|----  dynamic text  --- |
|                        |
-------------------------
```

I want the line surrounding the "dynamic text" in css.

I tried using &::before and &::after css, but still when the dynamic text changes i need to stretch/decrease that one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to set the width of `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements dynamically.

```js
function foo() {
  var ss = document.styleSheets;
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var totalWidth = getComputedStyle(box).width.slice(0, -2);
  var textWidth = text.offsetWidth;
  var lineWidth;
  var margin = 4;  // Set the margin between text and line.

  for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    var rules = ss[i];
    for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
      var r = rules.cssRules[j];
      if (r.selectorText == "#text:before") {
        // If you want the margin to be set on both sides of the line,
        // replace 'margin' with '(margin * 2)' in the next line.
        lineWidth = ((totalWidth / 2) - (textWidth / 2) - margin);
        r.style.width = lineWidth + 'px';
        r.style.left = -(lineWidth + margin) + 'px';
      } else if (r.selectorText == "#text:after") {
        r.style.width = lineWidth + 'px';
        r.style.right = -(lineWidth + margin) + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
}
foo();
```

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#text {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
}
#text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
#text:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"><span id="text">This is the text which is dynamic</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divWithBackground">

  <div id="divActsAsLine">

    <span id="DynamicText">Your text here </span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Now the CSS

```
#divActsAsLine{
border-botton:1px solid #00;
text-align:center;
}

#DynamicText{
 position:relative;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-bottom:-20px /*Adjust this based on your requirements*/
 z-index:1 /* optional */
}
```

The logic is to make a div margin as background line and make the span overlap this line, to do this we need to either decrease or increase margin property. you might need to use z-index if necessary

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle as per your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/prczLt5f/ The thing is, I need to give transparent color for dynamic text

Comment: if the background is color, you can use the same color to feel the transparency  http://jsfiddle.net/g0npozw9/ But since its an image we might need to think of another solution

Comment: No the background is an image.